# How to post data structure like json to flask?

Tags: python, json, post, flask

I have a data structure like this:

[image]

I'm try to send it to server by $.ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: post_obj, //this is my json data
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '',
    success: function(e){
       console.log(e);
    }
});
```

and I want get it in server by flask: `title   = request.form['title']`  working fine!

But how do I get `content` ?

`request.form.getlist('content')` doesn't work.

This is the post data in firebug:

[image]

Thanks a lot :D

Comment: How about `content = request.form['content']`? :)

Comment: @favoretti can't work: `BadValueException: Bad value for field of type "content".  Reason: "Value is not an instance of <type 'basestring'> (got: list)"`

Comment: Ok, and what does `request.form.getlist('content')` return? A bit more specifics about 'is not work' could help. Don't have a flask handy here to test unfortunately.

Comment: it's return the same error as `request.form['content']` . ps:  post data in firebug may help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are sending your data encoded as query string instead of JSON.  Flask is capable of processing JSON encoded data, so it makes more sense to send it like that.  Here's what you need to do on the client side:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    // Provide correct Content-Type, so that Flask will know how to process it.
    contentType: 'application/json',
    // Encode your data as JSON.
    data: JSON.stringify(post_obj),
    // This is the type of data you're expecting back from the server.
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/some/url',
    success: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

On the server side data is accessed via [`request.json`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.json) (already decoded):

```python
content = request.json['content']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect the POST being submitted by jQuery, you will most likely see that `content` is actually being passed as `content[]`. To access it from the Flask's `request` object, you would then need to use `request.form.getlist('content[]')`.

If you would prefer to have it passed through as `content`, you can add `traditional: true` to your `$.ajax()` call.

More details about this can be found in the 'data' and 'traditional' sections of http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Comment: when i set `traditional: true` to $.ajax.  i received a string like `[object Object]` in server...  but it's not what i want :(

Comment: Different server side technologies handle that differently. You may want to check out the answer about JSON provided by Audrius.